# Spring boot jersey - prevent startup instantiation of controller

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jersey

I am using spring boot with web and jersey (spring-boot-jersey-starter). I have a Jersey endpoint that needs to inject a request scope bean. However, at startup of the application I am getting a no bean found error.

```
@Component
@Path("blah")    
@RequestScoped
public class JerseyController{
     @Inject 
     private MyEntity entity;
}

@Component
public class JerseyConfiguration extends ResourceConfig{
    public JeyseyConfiguration(){
       register(JeyseyController.class);
       registere(MyEntityProvider.class);
    }
}
```

Is there a way, in a spring-boot web app, to prevent Spring from attempting to instantiate and inject my JerseyController until an HTTP request is received so that the injected dependency can be provided by my Jersey provider?

Comment: `@Component` is not required on Jersey resources. Having it will cause Spring to instantiate it (with default Singleton scope). I don't think Spring respects the `@RequestScoped`. This is a Jersey annotation. If you want to use the `@Component`, I think the Spring `@Scope("request")` might do the trick though.

Comment: That's it! Thanks. Was able to remove the `@Component` attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Component` is not required on Jersey resources. Having it will cause Spring to instantiate it (with default Singleton scope). I don't think Spring doesn't respect the `@RequestScoped`. This is a Jersey annotation. If you want to use the `@Component`, I think the Spring `@Scope("request")` might do the trick though.

You can also remove the `@RequestScoped`. This is the default scope for Jersey resources.

The only time I have ever found a need to use `@Component` on Jersey resources, is if I need to use the Spring `@Value` (maybe AOP also, but I don't do much AOP). Other than that, the Jersey-Spring integration already supports the most common used feature of Spring which is DI. And if you really want to make the Jersey resource a singleton, Jersey supports the `@Singleton` annotation.